# Algorithm to iterate N-dimensional array in pseudo random order

Tags: arrays, sorting, random, iterator

I have an array that I would like to iterate in random order. That is, I would like my iteration to visit each element only once in a seemingly random order.

Would it be possible to implement an iterator that would iterate elements like this **without storing the order or other data in a lookup table** first?

Would it be possible to do it for N-dimensional arrays where N>1?

UPDATE: Some of the answers mention how to do this by storing indices. A major point of this question is how to do it without storing indices or other data.

Comment: Your problem is your question! **Definition of "iterate":**  The process of repeating a set of instructions a specified number of times or until a specific result is achieved. -> Your original question said clearly "I want to iterate in random fashion" . So, we iterating number of times but randomly. However, since this is random, you NEED to remember visited places, or your iteration is no longer an iteration but just random visiting. Yes, there no problem visiting random place any number of times. But if you iterate, you need to remember where you visited. It is similar to visiting countries

Comment: I beg to differ as I know there is a solution to this problem that is purely mathematical not requiring storage of more than a few seed numbers. I just don't remember the name of it or the particulars of the implementation. Since I hope this may be useful to others I decided to ask on S.O.

Comment: Please, see my updated answer. And, again, if you truly iterate, or randomly visiting - you don't need to save visited places. If you randomly iterate - you do!

Comment: "I know there is a solution". Ok, give us solution. We'll wait. :o) Well, I know how to program things. Math... this is for Einstein. BTW. If you look into my solution, you don't really write to any tables. All you do  - you have control list from which you remove items as you already visited them.

Comment: @T.S. I finally remembered :-D Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to solve this, because it annoyed me to death not remembering the name of solution that I had heard before. I did however remember in the end, more on that in the bottom of this post.

My solution depends on the mathematical properties of some cleverly calculated numbers

```
range = array size
prime = closestPrimeAfter(range)
root = closestPrimitiveRootTo(range/2)
state = root
```

With this setup we can calculate the following repeatedly and it will iterate all elements of the array exactly once in a seemingly random order, after which it will loop to traverse the array in the same exact order again.

```
state = (state * root) % prime
```

I implemented and tested this in Java, so I decided to paste my code here for future reference.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class PseudoRandomSequence {

    private long            state;
    private final long  range;
    private final long  root;
    private final long  prime;
    //Debugging counter
    private int             dropped = 0;

    public PseudoRandomSequence(int r) {
        range = r;
        prime = closestPrimeAfter(range);
        root = modPow(generator(prime), closestPrimeTo(prime / 2), prime);
        reset();
        System.out.println("-- r:" + range);
        System.out.println("   p:" + prime);
        System.out.println("   k:" + root);
        System.out.println("   s:" + state);
    }

    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n
    private static long modPow(long base, long exp, long mod) {
        return BigInteger.valueOf(base).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(exp), BigInteger.valueOf(mod)).intValue();
    }

    //http://e-maxx-eng.github.io/algebra/primitive-root.html
    private static long generator(long p) {
        ArrayList<Long> fact = new ArrayList<Long>();
        long phi = p - 1, n = phi;
        for (long i = 2; i * i <= n; ++i) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                fact.add(i);
                while (n % i == 0) {
                    n /= i;
                }
            }
        }
        if (n > 1) fact.add(n);
        for (long res = 2; res <= p; ++res) {
            boolean ok = true;
            for (long i = 0; i < fact.size() && ok; ++i) {
                ok &= modPow(res, phi / fact.get((int) i), p) != 1;
            }
            if (ok) {
                return res;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public long get() {
        return state - 1;
    }

    public void advance() {
        //This loop simply skips all results that overshoot the range, which should never happen if range is a prime number.
        dropped--;
        do {
            state = (state * root) % prime;
            dropped++;
        } while (state > range);
    }

    public void reset() {
        state = root;
        dropped = 0;
    }

    private static boolean isPrime(long num) {
        if (num == 2) return true;
        if (num % 2 == 0) return false;
        for (int i = 3; i * i <= num; i += 2) {
            if (num % i == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static long closestPrimeAfter(long n) {
        long up;
        for (up = n + 1; !isPrime(up); ++up)
            ;
        return up;
    }

    private static long closestPrimeBefore(long n) {
        long dn;
        for (dn = n - 1; !isPrime(dn); --dn)
            ;
        return dn;
    }

    private static long closestPrimeTo(long n) {
        final long dn = closestPrimeBefore(n);
        final long up = closestPrimeAfter(n);
        return (n - dn) > (up - n) ? up : dn;
    }

    private static boolean test(int r, int loops) {
        final int array[] = new int[r];
        Arrays.fill(array, 0);
        System.out.println("TESTING: array size: " + r + ", loops: " + loops + "\n");
        PseudoRandomSequence prs = new PseudoRandomSequence(r);
        final long ct = loops * r;
        //Iterate the array 'loops' times, incrementing the value for each cell for every visit. 
        for (int i = 0; i < ct; ++i) {
            prs.advance();
            final long index = prs.get();
            array[(int) index]++;
        }
        //Verify that each cell was visited exactly 'loops' times, confirming the validity of the sequence
        for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i) {
            final int c = array[i];
            if (loops != c) {
                System.err.println("ERROR: array element @" + i + " was " + c + " instead of " + loops + " as expected\n");
                return false;
            }
        }
        //TODO: Verify the "randomness" of the sequence
        System.out.println("OK:  Sequence checked out with " + prs.dropped + " drops (" + prs.dropped / loops + " per loop vs. diff " + (prs.prime - r) + ") \n");
        return true;
    }

    //Run lots of random tests
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        r.setSeed(1337);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            PseudoRandomSequence.test(r.nextInt(1000000) + 1, r.nextInt(9) + 1);
        }
    }

}
```

As stated in the top, about 10 minutes after spending a good part of my night actually getting a result, I DID remember where I had read about the original way of doing this. It was in a small C implementation of a 2D graphics "dissolve" effect as described in Graphics Gems vol. 1 which in turn is an adaption to 2D with some optimizations of a mechanism called "LFSR" (wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register), original dissolve.c source code [here](http://www.realtimerendering.com/resources/GraphicsGems/gems/Dissolve.c)).

Comment: It will take me few days to digest. Hopefully I will have time for it. But I will check

Answer (score 0):

You could collect all possible indices in a list and then remove a random indece to visit. I know this is sort of like a lookup table, but i don't see any other option than this.

Here is an example for a one-dimensional array (adaption to multiple dimensions should be trivial):

```
class RandomIterator<T> {
    T[] array;
    List<Integer> remainingIndeces;

    public RandomIterator(T[] array) {
        this.array = array;
        this.remainingIndeces = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0;i<array.length;++i)
            remainingIndeces.add(i);
    }

    public T next() {
        return array[remainingIndeces.remove((int)(Math.random()*remainingIndeces.size()))];
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return !remainingIndeces.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

On a side note: If this code is performance relevant, this method would perform worse by far, as the random removing from the list triggers copies if you use a list backed by an array (a linked-list won't help either, as indexed access is O(n)). I would suggest a lookup-structure (e.g. HashSet in Java) that stores all visited indices to circumvent this problem (though that's exactly what you did not want to use)

EDIT: Another approach is to copy said array and use a library function to shuffle it and then traverse it in linear order. If your array isn't that big, this seems like the most readable and performant option.

Comment: Hi! I was a bit vague in my Question. I have updated it now. I really don't want to store any data to pull this off.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Imagine 3D array (you not likely use anything more than that). This is like a cube and where all 3 lines connect is a cell. You can enumerate your cells 1 to N using a dictionary, you can do this initialization in loops, and create a list of cells to use for random draw

Initialization

```
totalCells = ... (xMax * yMax * zMax)
index = 0
For (x = 0; x < xMax ; x++)
{
    For (y = 0; y < yMax ; y++)
    {
        For (z = 0; z < zMax ; z++)
        {         
            dict.Add(i, new Cell(x, y, z))
            lst.Add(i)
            i++
        }
    }
}
```

Now, all you have to do is iterate randomly

```
Do While (lst.Count > 0)
{
    indexToVisit = rand.Next(0, lst.Count - 1)
    currentCell = dict[lst[indexToVisit]]
    lst.Remove(indexToVisit)
    // Do something with current cell here
    . . . .  . . 
}
```

This is pseudo code, since you didn't mention language you work in

Another way is to randomize 3 (or whatever number of dimensions you have) lists and then just nested loop through them - this will be random in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a pseudo random number generator that generates values from 0 to X-1 and takes X iterations before repeating the cycle, where X is the product of all the dimension sizes. I don't know if there is a generic solution to doing this. Wiki article for one type of random number generator:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator